# ORM/Database library to persist external objects in Android

Tags: android, realm, ormlite, greendao, sugarorm

I'm writing an Android app where I have to persist objects, but these objects come from a dependency.

I've taken a look at libraries like Realm, GreenDAO, SugarORM, ActiveAndroid, ORMLite, etc., but all of these require access to the source files (classes need to extend some class, have annotations, etc.)

Is there any library which lets me configure the persistence scheme through a config or something? What are my other options?

Comment: You can map the external object from and to your new model objects?

Comment: Yes but I was looking for a solution where I don't have to duplicate code.

Comment: raw sqlite probably has that quality then

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any library which lets me configure the persistence scheme through a config or something? What are my other options?

ORMLite certainly allows you to configure your class using Java code, spring, or a config file.  See [documentation about class configuration.](http://ormlite.com/docs/class-config)

Here's a sample of how to use Spring:

```
<bean id="accountTableConfig"
  class="com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig">
    <property name="dataClass"
        value="com.j256.ormlite.examples.common.Account" />
    <property name="tableName" value="account" />
    <property name="fieldConfigs">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseFieldConfig">
                <property name="fieldName" value="name" />
                <property name="id" value="true" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseFieldConfig">
                <property name="fieldName" value="password" />
                <property name="canBeNull" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```